# Is there a way to create a magic item at less than its absolute minimum caster level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, dnd-3e, psionics, crafting

[Without using psionics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88520/8610), is there a way to reduce the absolute lowball minimum caster level of a [spell completion](https://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#spell-completion) magic item or [spell trigger](https://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#spell-trigger) magic item? Likewise, is there a way to brew a [potion](https://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-potions) at a caster level lower than is needed to cast the spell the potion contains?

---

#### Background

The benefit of the feat **Metacreative** ([*Psionics Handbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786918357) 27) says, in part, that

> You can create psionic items (including psionic armors and weapons, psionic tattoos, dorjes, power stones, and universal items) as if your effective manifester level were one less than your actual level (minimum 1st level). You must still be of high enough level to manifest the power in question. You can choose to use or not use this feat on each new psionic item you create.

The feat's examples then go on to clarify that this means, for example, a psionic item with a minimum manifester level of 3 (like a [dorje](http://alcyius.com/USRD/srd/equipment/psionicItemsCCDT.html) that stores a 2nd-level power) can be created by a creature possessing the feat at manifester level 2 *if* the creature has a manifester level of at least 3.

The prestige class [crystalsinger](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20011123b) expands on this idea, gaining—so far as I can tell—the unique class feature **metacreative creation** that's essentially a variant of the benefit of the feat Metacreative, but, instead of being able to create psionic items as if the crystalsinger were a manifester but *one* level lower than normal, the crystalsinger can ultimately create psionic items that are up to *five* levels lower than normal! (In all cases, there's a 1st-level manifester minimum.)

For example, a [psion](https://dndsrd.net/psionicPsion.html#psion) 9/crystalsinger 9 can create a dorje that stores a 4th-level power yet that has a manifester level of but 2. By comparison, when most creatures create a dorje that stores a 4th-level power, that power has a minimum manifester level of 7. (This *vastly* reduces the dorje's price: the former dorje's market price is 6,000 gp while the latter's is 21,000 gp! This also, of course, sometimes reduces the item's utility, but for many effects this isn't particularly important.)

I want to do the same thing that the crstalsinger does but I'd prefer doing so *without* using psionics and *especially* without using stinky, old unrevised [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) *Psionics Handbook*-era material!

***Note:*** I am aware that [a magic item's Caster Level isn't a prerequisite for the magic item's creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92382/8610). However a magic item's minimum caster level is *typically equal to the minimum caster level needed to* cast *the highest-level spell among the item's prerequisite spells. I'm interested in reducing the minimum caster level needed to cast the highest-level prerequisite spell so that, for example, attuned gems, etched runes, potions, scepters, scrolls, staffs, wands, and so on that hold high-level spells can be created at lower-than-the-normal-minimum caster levels.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Artificers can do that. Artificers count as 2 levels higher than they actually are for meeting caster level requirements (including those minimum caster levels for a given spell), but not for the actual crafted item. The explicit example given in *Eberron Campaign Setting* is a *wand of fireball* with caster level 3rd.

If you did want to use Metacreative, you could combine this with that by going with the psionic artificer from *Magic of Eberron*. *Magic Item Compendium* allows a psionic crafter to substitute psionic powers for spells when creating most magic items, so this doesn’t necessarily cost you all that much in terms of your crafting ability.

Comment: Is the 2-levels-lower as low as it gets, though?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am not aware of any other effect that offers the same kind of bonus, but I couldn’t swear to it not existing.

Comment: @HeyICanChan If you *did* end up wanting to use Metacreative, it may be worth noting the psionic artificer in *Magic of Eberron*.

Answer (score 3):

*@KRyan already mentioned that Artificers have a specific ability; I won't expand on this.*

Some classes may get access to spells slightly ahead of time. It only pertains to some select spells, and generally only reduces the caster level by 1 or 2, but that's already something.

---

Some Cleric Domains grant spells one level ahead of time.

For example, while [*Wind Wall*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/windWall.htm) is a 3rd-level Cleric spell, a Cleric with the [*Air*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm#airDomain) domain has *Wind Wall* as a 2nd-level spell.

A Cleric with the Air domain may thus craft a *Wand of Wind Wall* as an item with a Caster Level of 3 (and for a price of 4,500 gp instead of 9,000 gp).

---

Classes with a partial spell progression have specific spell lists; for example a Ranger level 8:

- has a Caster Level 4,
- can cast the above mentioned *Wind Wall* as a 2nd-level spell.

The above mentioned *Wand of Wind Wall* would thus cost 6,000 gp instead of 9,000 gp.

Or the infamous *Trapsmith* (*Dungeonscape*, p. 53), which has a number of 2nd-level/3rd-level spells such as *Arcane Sight*, *Cat's Grace* or *Haste* as one of its 9 1st-level spells.

---

Prestige classes with an accelerated spell progression also have an advantage here.

The *Ur-Priest* (*Complete Divine*, p. 70) has access to 9th-level spells at level 9, and its caster level is equal to its levels in *Ur-Priest* plus one-half of its levels in other spell-casting classes (excluding Cleric). Thus, a *Ur-Priest* with no other spell-casting class has Nth-level spells at Caster Level N.

The *Sublime Chord* (*Complete Arcane*, p. 60) also has access to 9th-level spells at level 9, and its caster level is equal to its levels in *Sublime Chord* plus its levels in another arcane spell-casting class. Early access to the class (before level 8), thus offers a reduced Caster Level for high-level spells.

---

*Note: beyond spell level and caster level, having Divine versions of spells is also useful to avoid the cost of materials; for example the Cloistered Cleric has Identify on its spell list, which avoids paying 100gp per charge when creating a wand.*

Comment: I don’t really think this answers the question (/I’m sure @HeyICanChan is aware of it), but if you’re going to go this way, the answer is incomplete without mention of the trapsmith from *Dungeonscape*. 1st-level *haste*, for example.

Comment: @KRyan is correct. This isn't actually *reducing* but, instead, *changing* the lowball minimum. It's close enough for a frame challenge, though, so I'ma not gonna downvote or nothin', but, yeah, trapsmith's a thing worth noting, as is, for example, ur-priest (9th-level spells at caster level 9!).

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I had completely forgotten about the accelerated progression of certain prestige classes; I've added Ur-Priest and Sublime Chord as examples. I really like this question, generally people try to abuse Ur-Priest to boost their Caster Level through the roof, not drag it down!

Comment: I'd just like to add that *base* classes with *slowed* caster level progression can also "dumb down" caster level. The one that's being used in a campaign I DM is mystic ranger (caster level = half mystic ranger level) (plus the feat Sword of the Arcane Order (*Champions of Valor* 34)). The party's wandmonkey saves literally 1,000s of gp making his own high-spell-level, low-caster-level wands (*and* has full BAB). (A mystic ranger can make wands of 4th-level spells cheaper than an artificer, but an artificer can make wands of 2nd-level spells cheaper and sooner than the mystic ranger.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: The Mystic Ranger CR is... weird. At level 1, it's got CL = 0, meaning its "Create Water" creates 0 gallons which is rather unexpected. I personally just think the class is ill-specified here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Mystic ranger is a strong enough class *and* had this specific advantage that the player *wanted* to play by the rules-as-written *just* for this purpose. *I* thought it was weird, but the PC just didn't cast spells until level 2, and it wasn't a big deal.