# Can you make spell trigger items at a caster level lower than your own?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, magic, crafting

Let's take a scroll as an example, but this would apply to wands and the like as well. The SRD says the following about scribing scrolls:

> The base price of a scroll is its spell level × its caster level × 25 gp.

Now assume a person of caster lvl 4 wants to make a scroll of a first lvl spell. Is there any way to make this scroll AS IF you are caster lvl 1? Thus letting all effects that scale with caster lvl be reduced to 1, but also reducing the crafting costs?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95077/8610) (and especially the question's note).

Comment: Interested: Yes. Though it does seem to mostly handle psionics, whilst I am specifically looking for magic and spell-trigger items.

Comment: Me, too! ("I want to do the same thing that the crstalsinger does but I'd prefer doing so without using psionics and especially without using stinky, old unrevised… *Psionics Handbook*-era material!")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, you can choose to make items at a lower caster level

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm):

> While item creation costs are handled in detail below, note that normally the two primary factors are the caster level of the creator and the level of the spell or spells put into the item. **A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.** Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: @HeyICanChan how is "no" the answer to the question's body? The question there is "is there a way to make the scroll as if you are level 1" and the answer is "yes", namely just by stating it?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've made it a bit more clear that it's lower level only.